# Perl simple search and replace

Tags: perl

I'm a novice. Sorry. I'm trying to remove commas. Perl cgi.pm
I need to know how to write this param('item_price' => ~ s/\,//g);
I can do this $item_price =~ s/\,//g; but would rather eliminate the conversion to variable.
What would be even better is if I can include removal of $. Can it be done? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You can only apply a replace RegEx to an l-value (an expression that you can assign a value TO), since it needs to write back the changed string.

From [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) for `s///` operator:

> Unless the /r option is used, the string specified must be a scalar variable, an array element, a hash element, or an assignment to one of those; that is, some sort of **scalar lvalue**. (As a note: `/r` modifier seems to be a new feature in Perl 5.14).

A subroutine/method call is NOT an l-value.

There are 3 workarounds possible:

- Assign results of the subroutine call to a variable, and run the RegEx on the variable.

  It may be slightly longer code, but it's clean, readable, and not bug prone. Best solution.

  ```
  (my $param_cleaned = param('item_price') ) =~ s/,//;
  ```
- Upgrade to Perl 5.14 and use `/r` RegEx modifier.
- [BAD IDEA!!!] If the param value is stored internally in CGI.pm, go into CGI object's internal storage and apply the regex to the value stored in the object. You should almost NEVER do that!

Comment: As a note: I'm aware of [l-value subroutines](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Lvalue-subroutines). They are new and experimental and NOT relevant to this question. Thus a comment, not part of the answer.

Comment: @ta - you are welcome. As per the way StackOverflow works, you can easily show your appreciation by accepting the most useful answer by clicking on "check" mark next to that answer (and you get 2 rep points for doing that as well).

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this in Perl 5.14, with the [*return* flag](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Binding-Operators):

```
my $result = param( 'item_price' ) =~ s/,//gr;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could, but I'm not sure it'd be more efficient.  Something like this should work:

```
join("", split(/,/, param('item_price')));
```

Comment: This is a neat hack but IMHO not one prone to easy readability.

Answer (score 1):

The question is unclear (due to giving invalid Perl as a description of what you want).

It sounds like you want to get the value and transform it inside of an expression.

```
do {
   my $item_price = param('item_price');
   $item_price =~ s/,//g;
   $item_price
}
```

or

```
use List::MoreUtils qw( apply );
apply { s/,//g } param('item_price')
```

or

```
# Requires 5.14
param('item_price') =~ s/,//gr
```

Where can use those? Anywhere an expression can be used.

```
# Print out the transformed value
print( param('item_price') =~ s/,//gr );

# Change the param itself
param( 'item_price', param('item_price') =~ s/,//gr );

etc
```